# Access Google Apps Domain user's personal contacts as administrator using api

Tags: ruby, google-api, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

I need to access Google Apps Domain user's personal contacts as administrator using api.

On "Google Contacts API version 3.0" there are information how to do this:

> Retrieving all contacts To retrieve all of a user's contacts, send an
>   authorized GET request to the following URL:
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
>  With the
>   appropriate value in place of userEmail.
>  Note: The special userEmail
>   value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user.

So I registered appliaction on Cloud Google Console
and got Client ID and Client Secret. As domain administrator I authorized application in
Security > Advanced settings > Manage third party OAuth Client access. Allowed: Contacts (Read/Write)  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/

My code on ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gdata'
require 'highline/import'
require 'yaml'
require 'oauth2'


client = YAML::load(open('data/client2.yml'))
client_id = client[:client_id]
client_secret = client[:client_secret]

tokens = YAML::load(open('data/tokens2.yml'))

api_client_obj = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, {:site => 'https://www.google.com/',:raise_errors=>true})
api_access_token_obj = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(api_client_obj, tokens[:access])


begin
    response=api_access_token_obj.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/user@mydomain.com/full?v=3")
rescue Exception => e
  puts "--- #{e.message} ---"
end

puts response.inspect
```

I skipped refreshing token part to be shot. No problems with it.
When I put my email on user@mydomain.com I receive valid response with my personal contacts.
When I request /m8/feeds/profiles/domain/mydomain.com/full?v=3 I successfully receive domain directory contacts. But when I use other existing domain user email I have error:

```
--- <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title> 
<style
 type="text/css">
 CUT CUT CUT CUT CUT CUT CUT 
 </style></head> <body>
<a
 href="//www.google.com/" id="g"><img> src="//www.google.com/images/logo_sm_2.gif" alt="Google" width="150"

 height="55"></a> <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That&#39;s an error.</ins></p>

 <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL
 <code>/m8/feeds/contacts/user@mydomain.com/full</code> from this server. 
 <ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p></body></html> --- 
 nil
```

Please help. Thanks.